# How to maintain an image's aspect ratio inside an SVG without an aspect ratio

Tags: css, svg, sass, cross-browser

I have an SVG functioning properly as a clipping path masking an image. The SVG shape has preserveAspectRatio="none" and is behaving how I want it to (full-width but maintaining a static height).

The problem is that the image I am clipping is stretching and squishing along with the SVG whereas I'd like it to behave the same as a background image with background-size: cover; (always filling the SVG, cropping if necessary, but maintaing aspect ratio).

Is it possible to do this with cross-browser compatibility (the latest Chrome, Firefox, Safari, and Internat Explorer)?

HTML:

```
<div class="outer-wrapper">
  <div class="svg-wrapper">
    <!-- hidden SVG -->
    <svg class="shadow-svg">
      <!-- create drop shadow -->
      <filter id="drop-shadow">
        <feGaussianBlur in="SourceAlpha" stdDeviation="5"/>
        <feOffset dx="0" dy="0" result="offsetblur"/>
        <feFlood flood-color="rgb(0,0,0)" flood-opacity="0.75"/>
        <feComposite in2="offsetblur" operator="in"/>
        <feMerge>
          <feMergeNode/>
          <feMergeNode in="SourceGraphic"/>
        </feMerge>
      </filter>
      <!-- create shape-->
      <symbol id="shadow" viewBox="0 0 100 100" style="enable-background:new 0 0 100 100;" xml:space="preserve">
        <defs>
          <polygon id="clipShape" points="0 0 0 260 20 260 20 210 1350 210 1350 260 1370 260 1370 0 0 0" style="filter:url(#dropshadow)"/>
        </defs>
      </symbol>
      <!-- set shape as clipping path -->
      <clipPath id="clipPath">
        <use xlink:href="#clipShape" />
      </clipPath>
    </svg>
    <!-- visible SVG -->
    <svg class="shape-svg" version="1.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" viewBox="0 0 1370 260" enable-background="new 0 0 1370 260" xml:space="preserve" preserveAspectRatio="none">
      <!-- add drop shadow -->
      <use xlink:href="#shadow" />
      <!-- add clipping path shape -->
      <g transform="matrix(1 0 0 1 0 0)" clip-path="url(#clipPath)" >
        <!-- add image inside clipping path shape -->
        <image width="1370" height="260" xlink:href="https://www.unsplash.it/1370/260" transform="matrix(1 0 0 1 0 0)"></image>
      </g>
    </svg>
  </div><!-- .svg-wrapper -->
  <!-- text block -->
  <div class="header-text">
    <h2>Test Header Placeholder</h2>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor, sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Velit exercitationem quibusdam sed natus blanditiis quia assumenda, magni tenetur veritatis itaque iure explicabo veniam maiores magnam architecto et corporis possimus.</p>    
  </div>
</div><!-- .outer-wrapper -->
```

SCSS:

```
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

body {
  height: 100vh;
  background: repeating-linear-gradient(-45deg, palegreen, palegreen 3px, lightgreen 3px, lightgreen 40px);
}

.outer-wrapper {
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

.svg-wrapper {
  width: 96%;
  height: 150px;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

.shadow-svg {
  width: 0;
  height: 0;
  position: absolute;
}

.shape-svg {
  width: 100%;
  height: 150px;
  filter: url(#drop-shadow);
}

.header-text {
  width: 90%;
  margin: -20px auto 0;
  font-family: monaco, courier;
}
```

[CodePen Here](https://codepen.io/ChrisBup/pen/LOzNeX?editors=1100%22CodePen%20Here%22)

Note: it's currently not working in Firefox or IE11. I'd appreciate any assistance in getting all this working across those browsers as well.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

**About the aspect ratio**

You could just set the svg as a background-image of a div. And style it with css; `background-size: cover;` and `background-position: center bottom;` will probably do the trick.

**Here is an answer of the question "why it doesn't it work in MS-Edge?".**

- Define your clipPath in a `<defs>` element.
- The defs element should be a direct child of one of the ancestors of the referencing element Which is not the case in your example. Placing the defs element as a child of the `<svg>` element always works. Source: https://www.w3.org/TR/SVG/struct.html#DefsElement
- Rule of life: Keep it simple when you can. That means not using unnecessary references. Just show the clipping path inside the `<clipPath>` element.
  The `<defs>` element ended up looking like this for me and is a child of the `<svg>` element.

```html
<defs>
  <!-- set shape as clipping path -->
  <clipPath id="clipPath">
    <polygon points="0 0 0 260 20 260 20 210 1350 210 1350 260 1370 260 1370 0 0 0"/>
  </clipPath>
</defs>
```

Answer (score 0):

instead of using  tag, you can use mask properties in CSS. It acts similarly like background properties.

I tried this one and solves the problem. https://clipping-masking.webflow.io/

```css
.masked {
  mask-image: url(domain.com/image.sv ), none;
  mask-size: contain;
  mask-repeat: no-repeat;
  mask-position: center;
}
```